# R: "if else if" vs "or" with three cases

Tags: r, if-statement

Im running through some old code to clean it up and saw an old `if else if statement` that brought up a question in my mind; this is a super simple logic question but for my own edification and to make sure I'm thinking about this logically I wanted to see if a change from the 'old way' to the 'new way', in essence for this case at least, would be the same. ***My question is: are these two ways of doing this essentially the same?***

```
 #old way
df_test = tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(column1 = NA))

if(NROW(df_test$column1) == 0) {
  df_test = TRUE
} else if (all(is.na(df_test$column1))) {
  df_test = TRUE
} else {
  df_test = FALSE
}

#new way
df_test = tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(column1 = NA))

if(NROW(df_test$column1) == 0 | all(is.na(df_test$column1))) {
  df_test = TRUE
} else {
  df_test = FALSE
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that should have been more clear

Comment: Yes, those tow are essentially the same. Your code could be simplified to `df_test <- NROW(df_test$column1) == 0 | all(is.na(df_test$column1))` since the evaluation of your conditions equals the value assigned to `df_test`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way of doing this:

```
df_test = tibble::as_tibble(data.frame(column1 = NA))

df_test <- ifelse(NROW(df_test$column1) == 0 | | all(is.na(df_test$column1)), TRUE, FALSE)
df_test
```

I believe that this is cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

### No, they are not the same

The reason they're not the same is because the `|` operator always evaluates the operands on both sides. However, in the `if(x) else if(y)` block, the second `if` is not evaluated if the first `if` is true. The difference is particularly important if the expressions being tested involve side-effects, eg if you are modifying files.

Another difference is that `|` is vectorised, ie it returns a vector of true/false values if its operands are vectors. This is usually *not* what you want in the context of `if` blocks, and R will throw a warning if a vector of length >1 is returned.

Simplified example:

```r
foo <- function()
{
    print("in foo")
    TRUE
}

bar <- function()
{
    print("in bar")
    TRUE
}

# case 1
if(foo()) x <- 1 else if(bar()) x <- 1

# case 2
if(foo() | bar()) x <- 1
```

The first case will print out `"in foo"` only. The second case will print `"in foo"` followed by `"in bar"`.

If you want to collapse the if block, use `||`, *not* `|`. This will only evaluate the right-side operand if the left side is false, and also only returns a scalar value, not a vector. This is consistent with how `if` behaves.